# Dotnetnuke (DNN) on azure websites - Are upgrades and module installs persisted?

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I signed up for the free azure website (not web role) and installed DNN 7 from the app catalog. So far so good.

**My concern:** The last time I checked (and I could be wrong) the application package that is published to azure is immutable and if you want to make changes to it, you must publish a whole new package to azure. Since DNN allows for upgrades and module installations, are these changes persisted? Can you still upgrade DNN by FTP'ing the upgrade package over the installation? If not how do you do it? I know about the dotnetnuke accelerator for web roles but I want to stick with the azure websites for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immutable thing is for Web Roles, not Azure Web Sites. If you make a change to a web site, it is persisted.

Comment: That's good to know. I couldn't find this info on azure documentation. Thanks.